# Internal vs external procedure/function

Tags: sql, plsql

What is the difference between a internal function/procedure to a external function/procedure? I tried to find it on Google but it doesn't come up much and i am still confused. Is it just where the function or procedure is put in the body?

Comment: If you can't find it easily on Google, maybe you should question the source from which you heard these terms. If they're using non-standard terminology then they're going to confuse everyone.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

external procedure or functions are standlone subprograms while internal procedures or

function are subprograms which is a part of a package and can be overloaded.

Comment: -1 this is a plain wrong answer. [Nested/package/standalone subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm) is different categorisation than external subprograms.

Answer (score 1):

See [chapter PL/SQL Subprograms](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/subprograms.htm) of [PL/SQL Language Reference](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e17126/toc.htm):

> If a C procedure or Java method is stored in the database, you can publish it as an *external subprogram* and then invoke it from PL/SQL.

Thus external subprogram is a function/procedure/method implemented in some other Oracle database supported language than PL/SQL. The external subprogram can be called from PL/SQL by defining a PL/SQL subprogram with a call specification. That subprogram is essentially just a wrapper around the non-PL/SQL subprogram.

I'm not aware of term internal subprogram. Maybe it's just an opposite of external ? I.e. a subprogram implemented in PL/SQL.